# Getting KERN-EXEC 3 while loading 3D object through VBO method in Symbian^3, why?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, symbian, vbo

I am currently getting KERN-EXEC 3 error when I click my app icon. Actually I am loading a 3D object through VBO method in Symbian^3. Meanwhile, I am not getting this error when I load relatively smaller object through the same VBO method.

Can anybody please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't given your app enough heap to work with. You can set it with the EPOCHEAPSIZE keyword in your MMP file.

http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_3rd_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/html/SDL_93/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities93/Build-ref/Mmp-ref/epocheapsize.html